# Reading XML with PHP. Not work (namespaces)

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I can read XML files or strings but not the next:

```
$str = <<<XML
    <Output xmlns="nice.uniform://" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Data i:nil="true"/>
        <Result xmlns:a="http://nice.uniform/CLSAPI3">
            <a:ResultCode>SUCCESS</a:ResultCode>
            <a:ResultMessage>OK</a:ResultMessage>
            <a:ResultCodeEx>CLS_SE_SUCCESS</a:ResultCodeEx>
        </Result> 
        <Exception i:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System"/>
    </Output>
XML;
```

My PHP code to read a node of XML file is:

```
$Output = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
echo $Output->Result->{'a:ResultCodeEx'};
```

Also, I've tried:

```
$xmlResponse = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
foreach($xmlResponse->Result as $xmlEntry)
{
 echo $xmlEntry->{'a:ResultCodeEx'};
}
```

//or

```
$blocks = $xmlResponse->xpath('//Output');
print_r($blocks);
```

Can you help me?

Comment: I'd say that is not a valid xml file.

Comment: @arkascha, I've validated xml file. It's valid

Comment: My PHP is rusty to say the least but; The XML is defined with a default namespace (nice.uniform://). the 3 deepest nodes are from another namespace (http://nice.uniform/CLSAPI3). When selecting items from this XML you must include the namespaces in the selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document uses several [namespaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/). The element `ResultCodeEx` belongs to the namespace `a`. You can use XPath, but you need to register the namespace `a` before the query:

```
$Output = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
$Output->registerXPathNamespace ('a', 'http://nice.uniform/CLSAPI3');
$result =  $Output->xpath('//a:ResultCodeEx/text()');
echo $result[0]; // CLS_SE_SUCCESS
```